# Unsupported method, post while using facebook score api

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

My problem is, while i post score using facebook php sdk it alwasys give error as Unsupported method, post.

Here is the code I use:

```
$app_AccessToken = $obj_facebook->getAccessToken();
$obj_facebook->api('/100003470602309/scores/', 'post ', array('access_token' => $app_AccessToken, 'score' => '154125'));
```

Comment: What method are you using?  Could you post code you use to post score?

Comment: $app_AccessToken = $obj_facebook->getAccessToken();
                       $obj_facebook->api('/100003470602309/scores/', 'post ', array('access_token' => $app_AccessToken, 'score' => '154125'));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be due to access token. Make sure you have an [**app access token**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-app/).

Comment: i have valid app access token, but it neither let me use POST,DELETE but allow to GET while using score api.

Answer (score 2):

use some thing like

```
$obj_facebook->api('/me/scores', 'POST', array( 'score' => 100, 'access_token' => $obj_facebook->getAppId().'|'.$obj_facebook->getApiSecret() ));
```

try this :p may be it will help